# Some ajax help?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a php script that takes some user form input and packs some files into a zip based on that input. The problem is that sometimes the server errors, so all the form data is lost. I was told I could use ajax instead so that the user never even has to change the page. I've never used ajax, and looking at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ without any experience in ajax is quite difficult.

The page says that you can accept returns from an ajax call. How do you set up returns in the PHP file for an ajax call? If the server errors with the ajax call, how will I know?

edit: Also, is there a way to send an ajax request with javascript and jquery as if it were a submitted form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How do you set up returns in the PHP file**

just **echo** it in ajax page that will return as response

*Simple Tutorial*

**client.php**

```
$.post('server.php',({parm:"1"}) function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
});
```

**server.php**

```
<?php

echo $_POST['parm'];

?>
```

**result will be 1**

edit on OP comments
*Is there a way to use ajax as if you were submitting a form*

Yes, there is

- You can use plugins like [jQuery form](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/)
- Using [submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)
- If you using [jquery validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate), you can use submit handler option

using sumit

```
$('#form').submit(function() {
 //your ajax call
  return false;
});
```

Comment: So the content of the page is the return?

Comment: What ever you want to return just echo it.

Comment: @user828584:simple tutorial is updated in my answer check this out

Comment: Is there a way to use ajax as if you were submitting a form?

Comment: OK, but how can I get the information that was submitted to use in the ajax request?

Answer (score 0):

every ajax function has a function param to deal with server returns.and most of them has the param msg,that is the message from server. 
server pages for example php pages you can just use echo something to return the infomation to the ajax funciton . below is an example

```
$.ajax({
  url:yoururl,
  type:post,
  data:yourdata,
  success:function(msg){
      //here is the function dealing with infomation form server.
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get information from PHP to JavaScript via AJAX is to encode any PHP data as JSON using `json_encode()`.

Here's a brief example, assuming your server errors are catchable

```
<?php
try {
    // process $_POST data
    // zip files, etc
    echo json_encode(array('status' => true));
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $data = array(
        'status'  => false,
        'message' => $e->getMessage()
    );
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Then, your jQuery code might look something like this

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax(this.action, {
        data: data,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            if (!data.status) {
                alert(data.message);
                return;
            }
            // otherwise, everything worked ok
        },
        error: error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // handle HTTP errors here
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. The server doesn't exactly error, but Chrome thinks it does because of how long it takes? Something like that. I asked on here and no one knew.

Comment: @user You may need to adjust PHP's `max_execution_time` setting. See [`set_time_limit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)