# Passing parameters from JS/Jquery on one page to PHP on another

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress, parameter-passing

I'm looking for the simplest way to use the POST method for passing parameters from javascript/jquery on one page to PHP on another page.

I should mention that both pages are PHP templates for wordpress pages, but I guess it shouldn't matter.

Would appreciate examples for code on both sides.

Comment: Well, I know how to use ajax to run code on a php page but I don't know how to open a php page and pass it parameters. Can you give an example?

Comment: Sounds like looking for ajax tutorial. have a look at my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199797/some-ajax-help/7199821#7199821

Comment: OK, I think I got it. Now, what if I don't want an answer from the PHP page, but I want open and stay on it? I wish you wrote an answer instead of a comment so I can give you the credit you deserve.

Comment: :if you think i helped you.please upvote that answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199797/some-ajax-help/7199821#7199821.because SO not wish to place duplicate answer.Thanks for your appreciation

Comment: Will be happy to. Can you please answer the question from my previous comment?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3579/discussion-between-gowri-and-ash)

Comment: gowri, I just saw your invitation for chat. I'm there if you can still chat. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'otherpage.php',
  data: $('form').serialize(), //you may want to give id of the form which contains elements you want to POST
  success: function(){
      //code on success
  },
  dataType: 'html'
});
```

---

**edit 1**
incase you want to specify your own parameters to send then use:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'otherpage.php',
  data: {
          paramname1 : "put_param_value_here",
          paramname2 : "put_param_value_here",
          paramname3 : "put_param_value_here"
        },
  success: function(){
      //code on success
  },
  dataType: 'html'
});
```

---

**Edit 2**: if you only want to post your own parameters to a page (no ajax. simple POST which will open the page then do the following)

```
function postToUrl(url, params, newWindow)
{
    var form = $('<form>');
    form.attr('action', url);
    form.attr('method', 'POST');
    if(newWindow){ form.attr('target', '_blank'); }

    var addParam = function(paramName, paramValue){
        var input = $('<input type="hidden">');
        input.attr({ 'id':     paramName,
                     'name':   paramName,
                     'value':  paramValue });
        form.append(input);
    };

    // Params is an Array.
    if(params instanceof Array){
        for(var i=0; i<params.length; i++){
            addParam(i, params[i]);
        }
    }

    // Params is an Associative array or Object.
    if(params instanceof Object){
        for(var key in params){
            addParam(key, params[key]);
        }
    }

    // Submit the form, then remove it from the page
    form.appendTo(document.body);
    form.submit();
}
```

call like this:-

```
postToUrl('otherpage.php', {paramname1: "value_here", paramname2: "value_here"});
```

code taken from answer on [JavaScript post request like a form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit)

Comment: And this will cause otherpage.php to show? Also, I didn't understand your note on the data line. I want to pass parameters from the current page to the one I'm calling and show it.

Comment: I thought you were looking for an ajax way to open that other page..
anyways, in you case you just need to make sure your <form> look like this:-

<form action="otherpage.php" method="POST">
...
...
</form> . plain simple html way to doing things!

Comment: You understood correctly. I am looking for an ajax way to open that other page, but I also want to pass it parameters. The `form` option is not very good since I have several buttons and each will open the same page but with different parameters.

Comment: updated again..postToUrl will POST your custom parameters to the new page..and since this is not ajax..your otherpage.php should open in browser

Comment: JamesSmith, thanks so much for this detailed response. You understood what I was looking for and I bet it would work so I'm accepting your answer. But this is getting too complicated for me and I realize now that my strategy was wrong and I should have done more work with PHP rather than JS, then I wouldn't have been in this situation. So I'm going to solve this by writing the params to the DB, redirect to the page and read them again. I know it's bad programming but this is just temporary. Right now I just have to finish building my site as fast as possible.

Comment: yea..sometimes..whatever-you-can-code-faster is the best way to go :)

Answer (score 2):

you can use query string parameters

```
$.post("anotherPage.php?param1=one&param2=two",function(data){ 
console.log("data"); //prints yahoo
console.log("success");    
});
```

or

```
$.post("anotherPage.php",{param1:'one',param2:'two'},function(data){ 
console.log("data"); //prints yahoo
console.log("success");    
});
```

in the php page

```
$param1=$_POST['param1'];//gives you one
$param2=$_POST['param1'];//gives you two

echo "yahoo";
```

**EDIT**

from the comment no JamesSmith answer i think you want to redirect to other page in that case

**Page1.php**

```
<script>
location.href='page2.php?param1=one&param2=two'; // this causes the page to redirect
</script>
```

**page2.php**

```
<h1><?php echo $_GET['param1']; ?></h1>
<h2><?php echo $_GET['param2']; ?></h2>
```

**yet another edit**

you can have a form in page1 and post it to page2

```
<form action="page2.php" method="post">
<input name="param1" type="text" />
<input name="param2" type="text" />
<input name="submit" value="Submit" type="submit" />
</form>
```

in page2.php

```
<h1><?php echo $_POST['param1']; ?></h1>
<h2><?php echo $_POST['param2']; ?></h2>
```

Comment: What does `console.log` do? What do you mean "prints yahoo"? Where did 'yahoo' come from?

Comment: Thanks, but I want to use POST, not GET. So, your original answer wont redirect to the new page?

Comment: no the original answer wont redirect to the page2 also in your scenario as far as i have understood you cannot use `POST` because the query string parameters are visible in the address bar so you will have to use `GET`.

Comment: Is there a way for the parameters not to be visible in the address bar? This is why I want to use POST and not GET if possible.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3580/discussion-between-3nigma-and-ash)

Comment: 3nigma, thanks a lot for the effort. It wasn't exactly what I was looking for but it was detailed and I'm sure others can benefit from it. So +1 on the answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can do what you wish to do in ajax success according to response

```
$.post('server.php', ({parm:"1"}) function(data) {
    if (data == 1){
        window.href = "your redirecting location";
    }
    else
    {
        //do something
    }
});
```

Comment: In my case `server.php` and `window.href` are the same. Isn't this like calling for the same page twice?

Comment: Also, I don't need a reply from the php page. I just want to redirect to it and pass it parameters.

Comment: you can't do that in server page .you can only do this in client page.I think php header location will not working in server page.

Comment: gowri, thanks for your generous help. It wasn't exactly what I was looking for but you get +1 on the answer.